# How to do DOM manipulation in Knockout JS after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, knockout.js

I know that you're not supposed to do DOM manipulation inside a model with Knockout JS and that the recommended way is to do a ko.bindingHandler.myDomManipulatingHandler. But what if a method in the model calls ajax and then must update both data and manipulate DOM.

How can I do this but still keep clean separations?

```
ViewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;

    self.saveToServer = function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "url to server",
            success: function ()
            {
                // data change code
                // dom manipulation code
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the specific DOM manipulation you need to do, but it seems like you could just update the corresponding observable.

```
var self = this,
    self.data = ko.observableArray();

/* snip */
    success: function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.data(), function () {
        /* update values here */
```

Comment: Sorry. Don't quite get it. Where do I manipulate the DOM? What if I need to manipulate DOM that is not data-bound?

Comment: @AdrianRosca in that case can you be more specific about what needs to be manipulated?  Perhaps set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: My specific example is too complex and too much code to put on jsfiddle. But it's basically a save button in a document editor. When the success returns from the server I need to run the code $(".editor").find("[data-dirty]").removeAttr("data-dirty");. The GUI manipulates too much DOM with contenteditable=true to be able to be completely data bound. So I would need a general approach on the separation to get a hint on how not to mixup DOM manipulation in my models. Custom bindings doesn't really cut it either because the DOM  change needs to be done after the ajax call.